# Maximum number of Vertex-Disjoint Path from Source to Destination(Undirected Graph)

Tags: graph, np

How to find maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths from a source to a destination in a undirected graph? There are no weights on the edges. The program should be able to display the number of paths and also display each path.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you show any work that you've done so far to accomplish what you want (even if it's not working)?  And what language are you using?  We need more specifics from you in order to be able to help you out.